# Is there any equivalent to COST and VOLATILE in Oracle (migrating from postgres)

Tags: postgresql, oracle, migration, oracle19c

My question is pretty straightforward:

I'm migrating functions from PostgreSQL to Oracle, and we have some functions defined with

```
COST 100
VOLATILE
```

Is there any way to do this on oracle or does Oracle manage it automatically?

`COST n` tells the optimizer that the cost of executing the function will be `n` (PostgreSQL has no idea how expensive a function is), and `VOLATILE` specifies that there are no guarantees that the function will return the same result for the same parameters, which is also used by the optimizer.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Nicolas actually wants to migrate the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `COST 100` and `VOLATILE` are the default values for user-defined functions, I suspect that you never consciously set them.  I would simply omit both clauses when migrating to Oracle.